# multiply each element in a vector by the next element[r]

Tags: r

```r
vector=c(1.007469, 1.007469, 1.007369, 1.007419, 1.007269, 1.007769, 1.007969, 1.007469, 1.007469 ,1.007469, 1.007469, 1.007469, 1.004469, 1.007469, 1.007469, 1.006469, 1.007469 ,1.007469 ,1.007469 ,1.007469 ,1.007869 ,1.007469 ,1.007469 ,1.007469 ,1.007469, 1.007469,
 1.007469, 1.007469 ,1.007469, 1.007469)
```

I was trying to find the accumulated interest rates, for that I need to add 1, in each rate(I already did that and saved it to the vector object), and multiply each one by the next, after that `(result_vector-1)* 100` in the result, how to multiply the first element of a vector by the next and etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593439/calculating-compound-interest-with-vector-of-rates/50593687

Comment: I think my title is more comprehensive and will affect more people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cumprod` if we need to return a `vector` of the same length with each value multiplied by the previous multiplied values.

```
cumprod(vector-1)
```

If we need to return a single product, then use `prod`

```
prod(vector-1)
```

Or with `Reduce` and `*`

```
Reduce(`*`, vector-1)
```

Comment: I thought you wanted to return the same length as original vector with multiplied values.  If you want a single value, use `prod`

Comment: Thanks, both this approach selecting the last value and using prod arrives at the right result.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a for loop:

```
v <- c(1.007469, 1.007469, 1.007369, 1.007419, 1.007269, 1.007769, 1.007969, 1.007469, 1.007469 ,1.007469, 1.007469, 1.007469, 1.004469, 1.007469, 1.007469, 1.006469, 1.007469 ,1.007469 ,1.007469 ,1.007469 ,1.007869 ,1.007469 ,1.007469 ,1.007469 ,1.007469, 1.007469,
 1.007469, 1.007469 ,1.007469, 1.007469)

res <- -100
for(i in 1:length(v)) {
    res <- res * v[i]
}
print(res)

cumulative_v = -100 * cumprod(v)
stopifnot(all.equal(res, cumulative_v[length(cumulative_v)]))
```

**Output:**

```
[1] -124.6208
```