# Speeding up a loop through a tibble (or doing it smarter)

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tibble

In R, I have a couple of tibbles with many rows (4 million or so). I run a loop through one of the tibbles to construct cumulative series based on the other tibble.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(PortfolioDevt)){
  if (PortfolioDevt$Period[i] == 0){
    PortfolioDevt$Assets[i] <- 100
  } else {
    PortfolioDevt$Assets[i] <- PortfolioDevt$Assets[i-1] * (1 + css$Return[i])
  }
}
```

However, I am really disappointed with the speed of this.

Am I making some beginner's mistake here? Is there a much faster way to do this?

PS: There is nothing wrong with the results, which are as expected, except for running time. :(

Comment: If you can provide a small sample of your input(s) and expected output, it's much more likely that somebody can advise you.

Comment: Provide a sample dataframe, and the expected results

Comment: Without seeing the data, this sounds suspiciously like a compound interest calculation, which you could do much faster - e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593439/calculating-compound-interest-with-vector-of-rates/50593687

Comment: @thelatemail Thank you so much for this. Using cumprod - new to me - speeds things up tremendously!